# deploy action hook not working in openshift

Tags: python, django, ssh, openshift

I have a deploy action_hook that used to work in Openshift.  Recently the paths don't seem to be working (as of today). The shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#this one is the deploy hook .openshift/action_hooks/deploy
source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python/virtenv/bin/activate
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/

echo "Executing 'python manage.py migrate'"
python manage.py migrate
echo "Executing 'python manage.py syncdb'"
python manage.py syncdb
########################### end of file
```

When I SSH into the app on openshift to run this I get the error:

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've changed the permission with chmod 777 but it won't run it.  Does anyone know why this might happen when previously these paths have worked in the past?  I've cd ed in to the $OPEN_SHIFT_REPO_DIR and manage.py is there so I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're wrong about an earlier line. I bet "cd" isn't doing what you think.

As the line before "cd", in your bash script, put `set -e` and leave it there forever. If a command fails, everything after is probably wrong. Don't let it keep going.

As the next line, put `set -x` and leave it there while you look at what it's really doing. You should remove it later.

Finally, the one that's going to get you, `set -u`. Fail on trying to use the value of unset variables. That's probably the problem here. Whatever is supposed to set "OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR" isn't doing it. There's your problem, I predict.

Also, put `pwd` and `ls` before your "python" line. See what is really there, according to the script.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the EOL from windows to UNIX and it's working now.  I'll look into the set -e and set -x commands (new to bash scripts)